# What music genre has noisy, distorted vocals and somewhat scary synth sounds?

Tags: genre

I heard 5 songs with these genre characteristics approx. 3 months ago, the genre used by these songs (ALL of them) had distorted and low pitch vocals, noisy and scary synth sounds (with vibrato, distortions) and beats were like the 808 drum machine.

Comment: No, they were from different bands, Their names (I think) were oooOO and Salem

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia article for [oooOOO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OOoOO) categorises them as [Witch house](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Witch_house_(genre)), from which this description :

> The music is heavily influenced by chopped and screwed hip-hop
>   soundscapes, industrial and noise experimentation, and features use of
>   synthesizers, drum machines, obscure samples, droning repetition and
>   heavily altered, ethereal, indiscernible vocals.

[Salem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salem_(American_band)) are listed under the same wiki genre article.